# Expected value of dirac measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

> Let $x_n$ be a series in $\mathbb R^d$. When does $\mu_n = \delta_{x_n}$ converge weakly?

This is my attempt to answer this. Weak convergence means:

$$\int f \, d \mu_n \rightarrow \int f \, d \mu$$ for all $f: \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and bounded, where $\mu$ is some probability measure.

Then I tried to compute the first integral and ran into problems. We have defined this integral via the Lebesgue integral. I think the result is this:
$$\int f \, d \mu_n = f(x_n) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (1)$$

**Is this correct?**

If so, I resume like this. Therefore, $(1)$ becomes:

$$f(x_n) \rightarrow x$$ for some $x \in \mathbb R^d$. Since $f$ is continuous and bounded, this series converges if and only if the series $x_n$ converges.

---

This seems like a simple task but I'm very uncertain if I've applied the definitions correctly or even understand them fully. Can someone give me feedback on this?

Comment: it's mostly correct, but you need to show that if $x_n$ does not converge, then there is a continuous bounded $f$ for which $f(x_n)$ does not convergw

Comment: It is  a **sequence**, not a series.